# Lag in kafka mirror-maker

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using kakfa mirror-maker to replicate kakfa between two data centers. Kafka have 15 topics with 5 partitions each. Mirror-maker have 5 producers and 5 streams and queue.enqueue.timeout.ms=-1 and its running on target data center. The normal lag offsets between source and target kafka is  less than 1k. But sometimes we are getting huge lags(more than 100k) for some topics and it is taking few hours to get stabilised. Its working fine for other topics with same load.
Can anyone help to identify the issue?